# How to edit imported shapefile description data in google earth desktop

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-pro

I have imported a line shapefile into google earth pro desktop which is displaying fine and in the right geographic location.

The issue I have is that when I click on the layer in google earth the description balloon that pops up has data in it which I cannot edit (see image below).

I would like to find out how to edit that data in the balloon so that data I put into the description shows up instead.

[image]

Comment: You can only view Shapefiles in Google Earth (even pro) but you can save to KML and edit.

Comment: Thank you. That comment got me on the right path. I saved the layer as a kmz and am able to edit the details of that file.

Comment: @Mapperz I saved as a kmz but the details in the balloon are still as in the photo I posted with my question?